# Select single record where "key = value" or "key is null" if no match by value

Tags: sql

Not a DB guy but need to get something done for work. The database contains configuration settings where the ID represents the configuration ID. When KEY is `null`, that is the default value for the specified configuration ID.

```
ID | Key    | Value
-- | ------ | -----
 1 | null   | 'joseph'
 2 | null   | 'john'
 1 | 'test' | 'joe'
 3 | null   | 'sam'
```

Trying to figure out how to select all of the unique configuration IDs and override the value based on the specified KEY.

```
declare @key varchar(250) = 'test'
SELECT ???

ID | Key    | Value
-- | ------ | -----
 1 | 'test' | 'joe'
 2 | null   | 'john'
 3 | null   | 'sam'
```

Tried a bunch of things, from `union` to `coalesce` to `full outer join` but nothing seems to get me closer to where I want to be.

Tried `where (key is null or key = @key) group by id`, but I wasn't sure if using MAX(value) was going to work for strings like `joe` compared to `joseph`.

I feel like I might need to select all of the null items into a temp table then join another select statement that searches by key, but I wasn't sure if there was a way to do it with a single query.

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. If you're trying to change a value based on a specified key then the key being null is meaningless (unless you're searching for the default itself). What exactly do you expect the select return results to be for a given ID?

Comment: Should a row with `ID = 1` and `Value = 'joseph'` really be discarded if there is a row with non-null `Key` column for this particular `ID`?

Comment: Sorry for the nonsense. I am trying to get the full list of configuration properties based on the specified key, and if there isn't a property for that key, then get the default property (the null property). @ConsiderMe, correct. I think the column names in my example are a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments I believe you're looking for this:

(This is SQL Server syntax, you didn't specify the server type.)

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable yt
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(Key) AS Key
    FROM   YourTable
    WHERE  Key IS NULL
        OR Key = @key
    GROUP BY ID
) inQ ON inQ.KD = yt.ID AND inQ.Key = yt.Key
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was trying to do, but how do I get the value as well?

Comment: Updated the answer to give you the whole row. Assuming the key only appears once.

Comment: while my real scenario is a bit more complex than my simplified example, I think this is enough to get me on the right path. seems to do what I need it to do, now I just have to integrate it into my existing query